# how do i sort through a json converted to list?

Tags: python, json, list, python-3.x

suppose I had an object like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "cat"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "dog"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "horse"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "turtle"
  }
]
```

I wish to write a function that can take an input id and tell me the associated name. 
if animal_list was assigned that list, how would I find which animal was associated with 6? animal_list[id==6]?

Comment: I'd suggest converting to a single `dict` keyed by `id`, so you could just do `complete_dict[6]` (and get an answer in `O(1)` time, not linear `O(n)` time).

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you could convert the list into a dictionary as @ShadowRanger said, but if you can't you could use list comprehensions with an if statement like this:

```
my_list = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "cat"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "dog"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "horse"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "turtle"
  }
]

def get_by_id(the_list, id):
    found = [dict for dict in the_list if dict['id'] == id]
    if found:
        return found[0]
    return None 

print(get_by_id(my_list, 6))

# will output: {'id': 6, 'name': 'dog'}
```

Answer (score 0):

animal_list is the list you gave in your question

```
animal_list = [
      {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "cat"
      },
      {
       "id": 6,
       "name": "dog"
      },
      {
       "id": 8,
       "name": "horse"
      },
      {
       "id": 10,
       "name": "turtle"
      }
    ]
def get_animal(id):
    found = 0
    for i in animal_list:
        if animal_list[i]["id"] == id :
            found = 1
            print animal_list[i]["name"]
    if found == 0:
            print "animal not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import your data as a JSON and work with it using a dict structure.

I've created a function that will return the animal name if there's a valid key, and none if key doesn't exists.

---

**Code:**

```
s = '[{"id": 2,"name": "cat"},{"id": 6,"name": "dog"},{"id": 8,"name": "horse"},{"id": 10,"name": "turtle"}]'

def search_animal(s, num):
    import json    
    data = json.loads(s)
    for d in data:
        if d['id'] == num:
            print(d['name'])

search_animal(s, 2)
search_animal(s, 6)
```

**Outputs:**

```
cat
dog
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "cat"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "dog"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "horse"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "turtle"
  }
]


id = input("Enter ID..! ")

for data in list:
    if data.get('id') == id:
        print data.get('name')
```